# Android Fragment bind a listener to view

Tags: android, android-fragments

I would like to try to bind a view from my fragment. But I don't have a clue as to how to implement that.

Below is what I have:

```
   public class FragmentRouteTransHeader extends Fragment {

EditText etDocumentNumber, etRouteCode, etSystemDate,
etRouteName, etRouteDescription, etRouteFuel,
etRouteDistance, etOdometerFrom, etOdometerTo;

Spinner spRouteType;
String[] routeTypeArray;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = 
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.routingmodule, container, false);
    initControls(rootView);
    return rootView;

}

private void initControls(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    routeTypeArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.routetype);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), 
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, routeTypeArray);

    etDocumentNumber = (EditText) view.findViewById (R.id.etDocumentNumber);
    etRouteCode = (EditText) view.findViewById (R.id.etRouteCode);
    etSystemDate = (EditText) view.findViewById (R.id.etSystemDate);
    etRouteName = (EditText) view.findViewById (R.id.etRouteName);
    etRouteDescription = (EditText) view.findViewById (R.id.etRouteDescription);
    etRouteFuel = (EditText) view.findViewById (R.id.etRouteFuelInLiters);
    etRouteDistance = (EditText) view.findViewById (R.id.etRouteDistanceInKm);
    etOdometerFrom = (EditText) view.findViewById (R.id.etOdometerFrom);
    etOdometerTo = (EditText) view.findViewById (R.id.etOdometerTo);

    spRouteType = (Spinner) view.findViewById (R.id.spRouteType);
    spRouteType.setAdapter(adapter); 



}
```

But I do believe that there is no onClick method in a fragment class. Any ideas how to do it? Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: on which you want set on click listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fragment should implement the OnClickListener interface and then you can  setOnClickListener(this) on your views